Curvature due to a Small Mass in Minkowski Spacetime
Flat spacetime is described by the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu \nu}$.  Now let's say that we place a small test particle with a very small mass in the spacetime (we could say the particle is spherical and non-rotating for simplicity) the spacetime is no longer flat but is still close to flat, so we describe it with the metric
$g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu},$
where $h_{\mu \nu}$ denotes a ''small'' perturbation.  I guess the perturbation is infinitesimally small in some suitable sense when the mass $m$ is infinitesimally small. Can we say anything else more specific or quantitative about the form of the perturbation $h$ apart from that it is ''small''?  What is the specific position dependence of $h$ as one moves away from the test mass and out to infinity, and so on?

Just use the Schwarzschild metric. The gravitational time dilation is a handy measure of how small the perturbation is: $\sqrt{1-r_s/r}$. For Earth, $r_s\approx$ 8.87 mm.

@PM2Ring I am getting slightly confused here, what changes if the particle is moving on a trajectory?

Your test particle is in an otherwise empty space, so there are no forces acting on it. Therefore, its motion is uniform, so you can choose a frame in which it's at rest. You may enjoy this recent question about the tidal effect of the ISS:   https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/58497/16685 The analysis there is purely Newtonian, but you don't need relativity for this scenario.

If you want a discussion, come to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar Some of the regulars there know a lot more GR than I do.
